# "has-error" not working when multiple <td>s are placed in a <div class="form-group">

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form where  some of the fields are in a table.
So there is a label in one td. and an input in another td. 
When i try to include them in a div and apply a "form-group"
and "has-error" on it. Then has-error does not changes color. 
Is it even possible to do it? I really need the color of both 
label and input to change to keep the form consistent.

```
<tr>
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error' : Form.name.$error.pattern && (!Form.$pristine && Form.$submitted)}">
<td style="text-align:right; width: 10%;"><label for="name" class="control-label">Name:</label></td>                                    
<td style="text-align:right; width: 10%;"><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="name" ng-required="true" id="name" name="name" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z]*$/" ng-trim="false">
<p class="help-block" ng-show="Form.name.$error.pattern && (!Form.$pristine && Form.$submitted)">Enter a valid name (i.e. Alphabets) only</p>
</td>
</div>  
</tr>
```

Comment: Try to inspect the elements, if the class is correctly added to you div. But first, you could probably get rid of the div itself and use the parent TR to have the correct html markup.

Comment: i have inspected the elements the< div> element does not seem to appear at all. although the <td>s are present.

Comment: Try removing the div, you should use the correct markup of HTML table.

Comment: Thanks for the efforts. The problem is solved. I have dropped the idea of placing everything in one div having the same class. Now I have placed the div same inside each td and its working fine.

Comment: Yeah, since that is the correct HTML, it makes sense.